# tinymce 4 how to add event handler

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, tinymce

In tinymce 3, it seems that we can do this with :

```
// Adds a click handler to the current document
tinymce.dom.Event.add(document, 'click', function(e) {
   console.debug(e.target);
});
```

What is the syntax in tinymce 4 ? 
Need to do it after tinymce initialized.

UPDATE : I tried (still don't work)

```
tinymce.bind("description", "keyup", function () {
  console.debug('here');
});
```

Comment: Have a look at the docs. http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:method.tinymce.dom.DOMUtils.bind

Comment: Yes I tried that. Still not working. I updated my question. See any mistake in my code ?

Comment: Wow, made a mistake there myself. God, that API doc is complicated to read. Alright, correct answer now below, and is tested... You just forgot the DOM (uppercase !important) in your code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This works :

```
tinymce.activeEditor.on('keyup', function(e) {
    console.debug("keyup");
});
```

Comment: add to all:
    tinymce.on('AddEditor', function(e) {
                e.editor.on('change', function (e) {
                    console.log('stuff');
                });
            });

Comment: It worked just fine here. Where did you found that info?

Answer (score 3):

Just to follow up on this, if anybody stumbles upon this in future. This in the old API:

```
tinymce.dom.Event.add(document, 'click', function(e) {
 console.debug(e.target);
});
```

Would now be correctly:

```
tinymce.DOM.bind(document, 'click', function(e) {
 console.debug(e.target);
});
```

So if you are getting the "undefined is not a function" error on .add this should solve your problem.

Comment: this is not working... i'm binding the "click" event to an element in the (editor) page, but when I click on it my function is not called!

Answer (score 1):

I needed the 'keyup' event to fire. This is how I got it to work:

```js
let editor = tinymce.get("my_textarea_id");
editor.contentDocument.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) { 
   console.debug("keyup");    });
```