# I want to capture keyboard events in tinymce editor using a userscript (i.e add keyboard shortcuts)

Tags: javascript, tinymce, greasemonkey, userscripts, tampermonkey

I want to add keyboard shortcuts to the button in tinymce editor. The problem is that I don't have access to the source code of the website. So this needs to be done using userscript(i.e tampermonkey, greasemonkey).

I have successfully created a script that added the shortcuts if I execute the script form the console available in the development tools of the browser, but this code does not work in tampermonkey or greasemonkey. The script is as follows:

```
    function simulate(element, eventName)
    {
    var options = extend(defaultOptions, arguments[2] || {});
    var oEvent, eventType = null;

    for (var name in eventMatchers)
    {
        if (eventMatchers[name].test(eventName)) { eventType = name; break; }
    }

    if (!eventType)
        throw new SyntaxError('Only HTMLEvents and MouseEvents interfaces are supported');

    if (document.createEvent)
    {
        oEvent = document.createEvent(eventType);
        if (eventType == 'HTMLEvents')
        {
            oEvent.initEvent(eventName, options.bubbles, options.cancelable);
        }
        else
        {
            oEvent.initMouseEvent(eventName, options.bubbles, options.cancelable, document.defaultView,
            options.button, options.pointerX, options.pointerY, options.pointerX, options.pointerY,
            options.ctrlKey, options.altKey, options.shiftKey, options.metaKey, options.button, element);
        }
        element.dispatchEvent(oEvent);
    }
    else
    {
        options.clientX = options.pointerX;
        options.clientY = options.pointerY;
        var evt = document.createEventObject();
        oEvent = extend(evt, options);
        element.fireEvent('on' + eventName, oEvent);
    }
    return element;
}

function extend(destination, source) {
    for (var property in source)
      destination[property] = source[property];
    return destination;
}

var eventMatchers = {
    'HTMLEvents': /^(?:load|unload|abort|error|select|change|submit|reset|focus|blur|resize|scroll)$/,
    'MouseEvents': /^(?:click|dblclick|mouse(?:down|up|over|move|out))$/
}
var defaultOptions = {
    pointerX: 0,
    pointerY: 0,
    button: 0,
    ctrlKey: false,
    altKey: false,
    shiftKey: false,
    metaKey: false,
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true
}

tinymce.activeEditor.on('keydown', function(e) {
    var e = e || window.event; // for IE to cover IEs window object
    if(e.altKey && e.which == 81) { //Alt + Q
         //alert('Keyboard shortcut working!');
         simulate(document.evaluate('//div[@id="mceu_3"]/button', document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue, "click");
         return false;
    }
});
```

In the above code `div[@id="mceu_3"]/button` is the `div` tag that contain the button to be triggered by the key combination.

Could any one please provide a solution, also I don't have much knowledge of tinymce editor, so a simplified explanation will be more helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem is timing and iframes.  Post a link to a page you are trying to modify and we can take a look.

Comment: The page that am working on is used only for internal purposes and it's confidential so I wont be able to share the link to the page with you. Can you tell me which part of the html code do you need to find the solution, as I can't give you the entire code for the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching for another day, finally I found the solution to my query [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19792406/tinymce-4-how-to-add-event-handler).

```
    tinymce.activeEditor.on('keyup', function(e) {
        console.debug("keyup"); 
    });
```